# Is there a way to trigger a "Ctrl+Shift+P" event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is bypass Chrome's built-in print preview for Window.open(), and instead open the system print dialog (which is the default for IE, Firefox, Opera). This can be done in chrome by actually pressing "Ctrl+Shift+P" - but is there a way to send this command via Javascript that doesn't require the user to actually press those keys?

Comment: I doubt it, as `window.print();` actually opens that dialog you don't want

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand what OP is asking for, [this is chrome's print dialog](http://screencast.com/t/rOndVsTkG), which differs from the [system print dialog](http://screencast.com/t/Wy1JwJJI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would seriously doubt this, considering it could be used to cause a DDOS to the printer.

Comment: OP's talking about opening the native print dialog instead of chrome's custom print dialog. No DDOS is possible from opening the dialog.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Right, but the browser is what actually interacts with the hardware. This question infers that user3337596 wants to trigger a print from his custom dialog (i.e. when the user clicks a button in his dialog), which would not be possible for the reason kguest mentioned.

Comment: @William, the question explicitly asks about opening the "system print dialog", which doesn't imply anything about triggering an actual print. The point is for cross-browser consistency, not about triggering actual print jobs on printers.

Comment: in short... i want to (from my javascript code) open the system print dialog. NOT chromes print preview. i was looking into disaptchEvents, etc. So is there a way to send a trigger or something that will open that print dialog box? Send the key codes and key events for ctrl shift and p?